# Job Search by distance isn't respecting the distance

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

The last couple of days job search by distance is returning jobs well outside of the query

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=stockport&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles includes jobs in Denmark which is a smidge further than 20 miles from the north of England :)

Comment: Notice: I am a little unsure about my vote here, because the dupe is much wider than this one. Anyway, I will still vote this question too, for even as a dupe it deserve visibility so that people may know.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist not a dupe in my opinion, since this one is about searching in the site itself while the other is about emails. Same root cause, true, but in this specific case I do believe two separate bug reports are fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the problem is that the duplicate one includes this too if you read the full post. That was my original idea.

Comment: I searched for dupes before I posted but the language in the two posts was different enough I didn't find it. I don't mind this being marked as dupe. The important thing is that the bug was fixed and my RSS feed reader isn't creaking under the strain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report, Paul. I've just deployed a fix that should bring those search results back closer to normal. Sorry for the bug.